# Spring AOP can't apply advice to interface

Tags: java, spring

I am learning spring the from book the "Spring in Action fourth edition" by Craig Walls. I am trying to apply advice to the method declared by the interface and I am getting Exception. When I apply the same advice to the class which doesn't implement anything, everything works fine.

Spring version - 4.3.2

Help would be appreciated.

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main"org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.fifczan.bean.UserService] is defined
```

**Code:**

Interface:

```
package com.fifczan.bean;

 public interface Service {

 void doTask();
}
```

Implementation:

```
package com.fifczan.bean;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class UserService implements Service {


public void doTask() {

    System.out.println("doing task");

 }
}
```

Aspect:

```
package com.fifczan;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class UserAspect {

//If i change Service(interface) to UserService(implementation)
//in pointcut  I am getting the same exception
@Before("execution(* com.fifczan.bean.Service.doTask(..))")
public void userAdvice(){
    System.out.println("doing sth before method doTask");
 }
}
```

Configuration:

```
package com.fifczan;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;


@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class AspectJAutoProxyConfig {

}
```

main :

```
package com.fifczan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import com.fifczan.bean.UserService;

public class AspectJAutoProxyTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AspectJAutoProxyConfig.class);

    UserService userService= ctx.getBean(UserService.class);
    userService.doTask();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for a bean of `UserService`, which is *the concrete class, not the interface*. Retrieve or inject a bean of type `Service`.